# Deploy ASP.NET application to .NET Core in Linux

Tags: .net, ubuntu

Having some conceptual difficulties. I want to do my development in Visual Studio and create a ASP.NET application, not a problem.

Then I have a Ubuntu server on which I installed .NET.

Now I want to deploy my code to .NET on Ubuntu. Is this just a matter of copying the publish code from Visual Studio over to the linux server?

And how do I make my site visible on the internet?

Thanks.